# Use a switch statement within a while loop to output votes for candidates,

Tags: c++, while-loop, count, switch-statement

I have 3 candidates A,B,C.
With user input, user chooses a candidate by entering A,B or C.
For each candidate voted, that candidate must score 1 and the rest score 0.
my output currently is:

Input Choice A: A is 1; B is 16; C is 0
Input Choice B: A is 0; B is 1; C is 0 (correct)
Input Choice A: A is 0; B is 16; C is 1

OR I have to use code that only outputs the candidate and the vote?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int votesForA, voresForB,votesForC, spoiltVotes;
    int votingstations=0, i, total;
    int count = 0;
    int sum=0;
    char candidate;
    char candidate_A, candidate_B, candidate_C;
    
     cout << "How many voting stations are there?"
     cin >> votingstations;
    
    for (i = 0; i <=4; i++) {
        sum=i;
        total=sum;
        sum++;
        
        cout << "There are " << total << " voting stations" << endl;
        
       {
         while (count < candidate_A, candidate_B, candidate_C);
          cout << "Which candidate got the vote? " << endl;
          cin >> candidate;
          cout << "You chose " << candidate << endl;
          count++;
    
         switch (candidate)
         {
             case 'a':
             case 'A':
             votesForA=0;
             candidate_A=votesForA;
             votesForA++;
         cout << "Candidate A's amount of votes is: " << votesForA << endl;
         break;
```

Comment: Please [don't post screenshots of your code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: Select all the text and then use your editor's "reindent" command (if it doesn't have one, get a different editor). This will expose several bugs. Then read about the logical connectives, like `&&`, and how to test more than one condition in your favourite C++ book. And pay more attention to punctuation.

Comment: I tried to paste your code into my IDE (so I can compile and debug it), but my IDE is having issues converting an image into code.  No code pasted as text == no help.

Comment: Actually, very little of your code makes any sense at all, and to be honest it looks like it's largely made out of guesswork. I would recommend that you delete the code, then take a few steps back and practice on smaller programs until you understand them (no trial and error allowed) before you attempt this again.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your formatting is hurting you, and will make it hard to understand what your problem is. Let's fix it:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int votesForA, voresForB, votesForC, spoiltVotes;
    int votingstations = 0, total;
    int count = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    
    char candidate;
    char candidate_A, candidate_B, candidate_C;
    
    cout << "How many voting stations are there?"
    cin >> votingstations;
    
    for (int i = 0, total = 0, sum = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
        sum = i;
        total = sum;
        sum++;
        
        cout << "There are " << total << " voting stations" << endl;
        
        {
            while (count < candidate_A, candidate_B, candidate_C);
            
            cout << "Which candidate got the vote? " << endl;
            cin >> candidate;
            cout << "You chose " << candidate << endl;
            count++;
            
            switch (candidate)
            {
                case 'a':
                case 'A':
                    votesForA = 0;
                    candidate_A = votesForA;
                    votesForA++;
                    cout << "Candidate A's amount of votes is: " << votesForA << endl;
                    break;
```

So now , before I can answer your question, we've gotta talk about some code problems.

1. You don't have a switch statement in a while loop. The while loop does nothing currently
2. You declare a random scope (extraneous curly braces)
3. Your while loop condition doesn't make sense.
4. You're going to print 0 for the number of voting stations

I'm not sure what your condition is supposed to be, so I'm going to make an assumption that you want either the total of all the votes < number of voting stations.

In which case here's what I think will fix some of the issues with your code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int votesForA, voresForB, votesForC, spoiltVotes;
    int votingstations = 0, total, i;
    int count = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    
    char candidate;
    char candidate_A, candidate_B, candidate_C;
    
    cout << "How many voting stations are there?"
    cin >> votingstations;
    
    for (i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
        sum = i;
        total = sum;
        sum++;
        
        cout << "There are " << votingstations << " voting stations" << endl;
        
        while (count < votingstations)
        {
            cout << "Which candidate got the vote? " << endl;
            cin >> candidate;
            cout << "You chose " << candidate << endl;
            count++;
            
            switch (candidate)
            {
                case 'a':
                case 'A':
                    votesForA = 0;
                    candidate_A = votesForA;
                    votesForA++;
                    cout << "Candidate A's amount of votes is: " << votesForA << endl;
                    break;
```

Now, at this point, I'm not completely sure what you're asking, but this will allow you to loop through each voting station until you've reach `votingstations` number of votes using a while loop. Each time, only the candidate who got the vote will have a message printed using a switch. That sounds like what you're asking for to me.

Here's the output vs input:

Output:

`How many voting stations are there?`

Input:

`3`

Output:

`There are 3 voting stations`

`Which candidate got the vote?`

Input:

`a`

Output:

`You chose a`

`Candidate A's amount of votes is: 1`

`Which candidate got the vote?`

Input:

`A`

Output:

`You chose A`

`Candidate A's amount of votes is: 2`

`Which candidate got the vote?`

Input:

`B`

Output:

`You chose B`

`Candidate B's amount of votes is: 1`

At this point the total number of votes is equal to `votingstations` and the while loop exits and your for loop repeats.

There's a lot of useless variables and redundancy in your code, but I'm not trying to fix that obviously as you may being using those later in your program.